# Helper function to define string results?

Tags: verilog

In my Verilog code, I have such statements

```
$display("    %s r%h, r%h",
         instrH == ALU8_ADD ? "add" :
         instrH == ALU8_ADC ? "adc" :
         instrH == ALU8_SUB ? "sub" :
         instrH == ALU8_SBC ? "sbc" :
         instrH == ALU8_OR  ? "or" :
         instrH == ALU8_AND ? "and" :
         instrH == ALU8_TCM ? "tcm" :
         instrH == ALU8_TM  ? "tm" :
         instrH == ALU8_CP  ? "cp" :
         instrH == ALU8_XOR ? "xor" : "?",
         secondH, secondL);
```

which are helpful for the test bench debug logging. I want to extract this part

```
         instrH == ALU8_ADD ? "add" :
         instrH == ALU8_ADC ? "adc" :
         instrH == ALU8_SUB ? "sub" :
         instrH == ALU8_SBC ? "sbc" :
         instrH == ALU8_OR  ? "or" :
         instrH == ALU8_AND ? "and" :
         instrH == ALU8_TCM ? "tcm" :
         instrH == ALU8_TM  ? "tm" :
         instrH == ALU8_CP  ? "cp" :
         instrH == ALU8_XOR ? "xor" : "?",
```

into some kind of "function", so this is just defined at one location and use it later similar to:

```
$display("    %s r%h, r%h",
         alu8OpName(instrH),
         secondH, secondL);
```

How can I define a function returning a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `string` types in Verilog. You can declare a bit vector with multiple of 8-bit bytes to hold the largest possible string literal and return that. Null bytes 8'h00 get printed as spaces.

```
function [1:3*8] alu8OpName( //maximum of 3 characters
    input [3:0] instrH);
begin
    alu8OpName = instrH == ALU8_ADD ? "add" :
                 instrH == ALU8_ADC ? "adc" :
                 instrH == ALU8_SUB ? "sub" :
                 instrH == ALU8_SBC ? "sbc" :
                 instrH == ALU8_OR  ? "or" :
                 instrH == ALU8_AND ? "and" :
                 instrH == ALU8_TCM ? "tcm" :
                 instrH == ALU8_TM  ? "tm" :
                 instrH == ALU8_CP  ? "cp" :
                 instrH == ALU8_XOR ? "xor" : "?";
end
endfunction
```

But this kind of nested conditional operator is better written as a case statement.

```
function [1:3*8] alu8OpName( //maximum of 3 characters
    input [3:0] instrH);
case (instrH)
   ALU8_ADD: alu8OpName = "add";
   ALU8_ADC: alu8OpName = "adc";
   ALU8_SUB: alu8OpName = "sub";
   ...
   default:  alu8OpName = "???";
endcase
endfunction
```

And if you are using SystemVerilog, this would be much easier to write with a string function

```
function string alu8OpName(
    input [3:0] instrH);
case (instrH)
   ALU8_ADD: return "add";
   ALU8_ADC: return "adc";
   ALU8_SUB: return "sub";
   ...
   default:  return "?";
endcase
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a `function` that returns a `string` type.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 13.4 *Functions*.  This requires you to enable SystemVerilog features in your simulator.

Here is a runnable example:

```
module tb;

function string alu8OpName (int instrH);
    case (instrH)
        0       : return "add" ;
        1       : return "adc" ;
        2       : return "sub" ;
        3       : return "sbc" ;
        4       : return "or"  ;
        5       : return "and" ;
        6       : return "tcm" ;
        7       : return "tm"  ;
        8       : return "cp"  ;
        9       : return "xor" ;
        default : return "?"   ;
    endcase
endfunction

initial begin
    $display("    %s", alu8OpName(5));
    $display("    %s", alu8OpName(8));
    $display("    %s", alu8OpName(33));
end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
and
cp
?
```

You can use the conditional operator as your code shows, or use a `case` statement instead.